# Flask cli can't import application set with FLASK_APP

Tags: python, flask

Following the Flask 0.11 documentation, I cloned the Flask repo, created a virtualenv, and installed Flask via `pip install flask`.  I went into the `examples/flaskr` directory, set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable, then executed:

```
flask run
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\GitHub\flask\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 478, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 345, in main
    return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1094, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 316, in get_command
    rv = info.load_app().cli.get_command(ctx, name)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 209, in load_app
    rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
  File "d:\github\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 89, in locate_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'flaskr'
```

How do I correctly run the flaskr example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was setting `FLASK_APP=flaskr`.  Since I hadn't installed my app as a package in my virtualenv, I needed to add the `.py` extension.

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask issue for the eclipse and PyDev extension, you can set a path like this.
Flask 1.0.2 and Python 3.6 already installed on Windows 10.

[image]

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: module 'src' has no attribute 'Hello'
```

Run Flask in proper folder path to resolve this issue.

[image]